# Moshi converter array

Tags: android, arrays, json, moshi

I have a JSON document like this:

```
{ 
  cards: [{name: "Foo"}, {name: "Bar"}]
}
```

How do I make moshi only parse the array under the attribute cards.

Comment: you can mark all other attributes except cards as  transient in your POJO

Answer (score 0):

First, you have an error in Jason.

card => "card" .....

```
      String jsonResponseBody  = "{\n" +
            "    \"cards\": [\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "            \"name\": \"Foo\"\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "            \"name1\": \"Bar\"\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "    ]\n" +
            "}";

    Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();
    JsonAdapter<BlackjackHand> jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(BlackjackHand.class);

    try {
        BlackjackHand blackjackHand = jsonAdapter.fromJson(jsonResponseBody);
        System.out.println(blackjackHand);
        Log.e("TAG", "onCreate: "+blackjackHand.cards.get(0).name +"");
        Log.e("TAG", "onCreate: "+blackjackHand.cards.get(0).name1 +"");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

class BlackjackHand :

```
    public class BlackjackHand {
    public final List<Card> cards;


    public BlackjackHand(List<Card> cards) {
        this.cards = cards;
    }
}
```

class Card:

```
public class Card {
    public final String name;
    public final String name1;

    public Card(String name, String name1) {
        this.name = name;
        this.name1 = name1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We create a data class with the json list name and we specify it with @Json, it will be a list and we have received data as a list.

```
data class Model(@Json(name = "name") val name: String)

data class ModelList(@Json(name = "cards") val cards: List<Model>)
```

Comment: Please add an explanation as to why it works to make it more effective

Comment: We create a data class with the json list name and we specify it with @Json, it will be a list and we have received data as a list.